# PHP Redirect after images load

Tags: php, redirect

I am using an image with PHP src for checking did user who clicks on link disable images in the browser.

example:

```
<image src="some.php?someparameter=1">
```

If image load, PHP load link and save parameter to the DB, then redirect to another page

```
redirect('someurl.com');
```

A page is redirected before the image is loaded, how to redirect only after the image part is rendered? All code most be in PHP?

I test with sleep(), but not work?

Comment: That is not possible using server-side techniques alone. The browser has already received the response to its request for the HTML document that contains this image, before it loads the image - that request is done and finished, you can not redirect it "later." (And that you even considered sleep() indicates that you don't really have a clue as to how the different techniques and parties involved interact with each other - so time to get some understanding of the basics first.)

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side language. To make it clear, all server-side language run before the page even loads. Therefore if you specify a redirect in php, it will redirect before the page fully loads. You can use JavaScript to redirect the page:

```
window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/");
```

I am unsure how to code the redirect after the image has loaded, but I'm sure a quick Google search would find you the answer. I tend to use jQuery for ease, so perhaps look into using jQuery. Hope this helps.